# Can I create slideshow for videos in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: script-webpart, video-richmedia

I have embedded videos using script editor. When I embed multiple videos, the videos are not aligned next to each other. I want something like youtube has where you can autoplay videos, is there a way to achieve this in sharepoint 2013?
I know there is a picture library for slideshow, but couldn't see one for video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of jQuery plugins you can get working with SharePoint to do a slideshow type effect for the videos.  I would recommend not storing your videos on SharePoint.  There are too large and will take up too much space in you libraries.  Put you videos on Youtube or somewhere outside and reference them. There is nothing OOTB that will work for what you are trying to do though.

Comment: @user10  I would recommend using https://stream.microsoft.com to store videos! The algorithms there parse the videos for subtitling, the ability to search for people in the videos (can break video up to watch only a specific person speak, if you want), and even just do a text search for the transcript of the video. All this automatically :P